# How do I check if a JWT token is valid in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, microservices

I've set up a microservice (A) that generates JWT tokens and now I want to validate these tokens in another microservice (B).

How do I validate on (B) that the token generated by (A) is indeed correct? I wan't to simply check if it's valid, has a certain role in the claims, and if yes, to allow for a POST request.

I'm still a beginner to this and don't know how I could do that.

I already got the validation working on microservice (A), but that requires the UserDetailsService to be implemented, which I don't want to do in (B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For JWT validation in Spring boot, I would recommend using the Maven dependency [jjwt](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt)

You can validate a token by creating a method as follows

```
//validate token
public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
    final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
    return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
}

//retrieve username from jwt token
public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
    return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
}


public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
    final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
    return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
}

//for retrieveing any information from token we will need the secret key
private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
    return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
@Service
public class JwtUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws 
 UsernameNotFoundException {
    //TODO: return user details object
  }
}

public static Jws<Claims> parseJwt(String token) {
 Jws<Claims> jwt = Jwts.parserBuilder()
        .setSigningKey(yoursigningkey)
        .build()
        .parseClaimsJws(token);
 //once you have parsed the claims then validate it based on the  
 //user attribute
}
```

Comment: Where do I get the UserDetails from in microservice (B)?

Comment: You would need to create a Service and expose a method that will take the username as input and return an object of the UserDetails class. I have updated my code for the same

Comment: Doesn't that mean that microservice (B) also needs to access the User DB for that? All I have is the JWT token and private key in microservice (B)

Comment: No. If you have the JWT Token with private key you would just need to parse it and then validate it. I have updated the code with a function for the same